# Move debugger up the stack in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

Visual studio (I'm using Community 2015) allows you to drag and drop the yellow execution pointer around in the same function.

Is there a way to move that pointer up the stack, and especially when the debugger is waiting on the user after an exception has been thrown?

EDIT: Ideally no user code should execute during that process, as it can mess things up with other variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way. This is maybe not the easiest way around, but it's always possible to

- first drag and drop the yellow arrow to the end of the current function
- the execute as many step-out (Shift-F11) and "drag-to-end-of-function" as required

Of course it will "execute" some code, but if carefully done, it's only stack managing code, not user code, thus should not interfere with user variables.

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, PPC, if so, would you please mark it as the answer, so it would help other community members who meet the same issue as yours.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT: It's been open long enough, I'm not hoping anymore answer, then closing the subject

Comment: If it is so simple - I wonder why there is no such button like "Reset Frame" in IntelliJ IDEA ?!

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'Step Out' functionality.

> Shift + F11

is the shortcut by default.

Just a caveat: stepping out **will execute the rest of the code in the method before** going back up the stack.

Comment: Step out does execute all code to end of method, which is not desirable in some cases

Comment: Sure, but you did not mention anything about not wanting that in your question. I will edit my answer to include a warning about this